# Registering Users to a Login Database - Web Frontend?

Tags: sql-server, web-applications, odbc

I have a database which manages login information for an application, and find myself (for rather tragic reasons involving combo boxes - don't ask) needing to manage the registration of new users through a web frontend. Quite literally all it needs to do is have a single form composed of a few edit boxes and a handful of combo boxes. Keeping in mind that I'm completely inept and possessed of functionally no previous experience as a web programmer, how would one suggest going about making this form? (If there's a solution that keeps web simplicity but is functionally heavy on C++, or less ideally Java, I'm all ears.)

As a bonus question, it would also be useful (but, I imagine, rather difficult) to have one of the combo boxes update with information pulled from a SELECT query to the database. Is this possible for a web design beginner like me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you just want a web interface to login/create a user account?

Since I have a heavy C++ background, I would have done that with PHP, CSS and SQL. With PHP you can access your database in any way you want with SQL. Use CSS to display faulty fields in the user interface.

I run an Apache server with PHP5 and MySQL.

I'm I on the right track? or did you mean something else?
If this is what you are looking for let me know and I can try to help you a bit further.

Comment: Yep, you're on the right track. My knowledge of CSS is sketchy at best, but after a good bit of search & trudge I managed to get a basically functional Tomcat server up with PHP and MSSQL.

Comment: Did you manage to do the interface you wanted?
The combo dropdown is no problem to do with PHP. Did you manage to solve it?